# unable to resolve class org.grails.activiti.ActivitiConstants

Tags: grails, activiti

I upgraded my Grails project from version 2.3.4 to version 2.4.1. I received below exception. I am already using latest version of Activiti plugin version 5.12.1.

```
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[groovyc] /home/basil/Basil/Grails/WorkSource/Test/workspace/nssp/grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class org.grails.activiti.ActivitiConstants
[groovyc]  @ line 8, column 1.
[groovyc]    import org.grails.activiti.ActivitiConstants
```

Comment: How are you building, ant ? Did you check the classpath?

Comment: just to have it asked: have done the usual `rm -rf target && grails package` raindance? are the dependencies looking right? `grails dependency-report`

Comment: @Rao, Grails - > refresh dependencies is a maven build.

Comment: @cfrick, this issue is related to existence of grails depreciated apis in activiti plugin.